# Do the stored procedures take some physical space in the database?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, database-performance

I know, that using indexes in the DB can increase its performance, but since indexes take up a certain amount of physical space of DB, when using unappropriately, they can also cause slowing down DB performance.

I had then a similar thought about stored procedures, but could not find and answer for that. So: Do the stored procedures take some physical space in the database?

If so, can it be so significant that it could slow down a performance of inline sql performed in DB?

Comment: The effect an index has on performance is mostly when doing inserts. The database needs to so some work on each index you have on the table. That's why performance slows down. Stored Procedures have nothing to do with that. Their performance has more to do with how you code them.

Comment: From personal experience I've run into the issue Bob mentioned above. 20+ very wide indexes per table and most of them were never used. Dealing with a high number of inserts made the disk I/O skyrocket and killed performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In today's world there is no worry about physical space. And there are lots of benefits of using stored procedure. It's not gonna affect performance unless you write some sql queries in stored procedure which has some performance issue. So it's query who will degrade performance rather than the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

When we run something to the database, the database actually will spend time to work out a plan. Even a simple query like "select * from table", the DB needs some time to work out how to run this query. If you wrap your query to a store procedure, the exec plan of this stored procedure will be stored. Next time the DB can just pick up an existed exec plan to run. it will save time.Hope this helps.

As the other person indicated, performance is not about space, nothing to do with space.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. Even dynamic sql or pass through sql generates a plan. Those plans are stored in the cache. You would not want a stored procedures execution plan to never change. It should change when the quantity of data changes enough to warrant a different plan. If they were permanently stored as you suggested we would see in time that stored procedures would perform quite badly. Thankfully that is not the case.

Comment: Here is a link which explains in more detail how plan caching works.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx